# Mac SDL+OpenGL App refuses to launch from anything but terminal

Tags: macos, opengl, shared-libraries, sdl

We've got a [fairly mature cross-platform game engine](http://www.frogatto.com/) which we've had running on OSX for several years now without a hitch; we recently upgraded the game from SDL 1.2.15 to 2.0, and at some point in the conversion, I goofed something up and now we have a bizarre problem where the app launches just fine from the terminal, but when you launch the app from a double-click in the Finder, it just bounces once in the dock and just goes away.

We're baffled because insofar as I can tell, there's only a one-liner being printed in Console.app: `Exited with code: 255` (naturally running from the terminal doesn't help here because we can't reproduce the problem there; the app runs fine when launched in a terminal).

So the only thing we can figure is it's either something we're goofing up in our main.cpp, or something we've hosed in how I set up the dylibs/frameworks.  It's also possible that it's something to do with the working directory not being set right, but to the best of my abilities, I believe we're doing it right (regardless of your current working directory; the app attempts to forcibly set said directory to be in the Resources folder - this was necessary to get the game to launch, but I don't know if we're doing it wrong).  This feels like a somewhat awkward fit for stackoverflow, for which I apologize, since it's not a simple "paste this code and ask what's wrong" job.  I have two ways for you to reproduce it; firstly we are an open-source project, and you can get our source code (complete with a mac project file and all dependencies included in the repo, set up and ready-to-go exactly as I've perhaps erroneously created them), [at our github page](http://github.com/anura-engine/anura).  The one change you'll need to do is open a file at the root level, named `master-config.cfg`, and remove the `//` comments from it (so the engine knows you want to launch a simple demo game shipped with the engine).

Alternately, I have a stripped down (~15mb zipped) [binary you can directly download](http://frogatto.com/devbuilds/FrogattoLaunchTestCase1.app.zip) and try to run, if that's sufficient to diagnose the problem.

As said before, we're open-source, so we welcome any pull-requests for fixes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a minimal Cocoa wrapper so that OS X will not `SIGKILL` you for not launching properly. I will give you a pull request with that wrapper.

Comment: So we found the problem; someone else who tried it had more data output to the console than when we did, for some reason. It turns out the issue was that the -psn or whatever argument that the Finder passes in used to be handled by SDLMain, but now our main() was getting it, and quitting because of that. Anyway, this is an interesting idea, and the only answer, so I gave you the bounty.